# Does Checkstyle require compiled classes?

Tags: java, checkstyle

Can anyone confirm that Checkstyle is meant to be run with the compiled versions of classes on the classpath?

We currently run it on the Java files alone but recently we've been encountering some errors around the "RedundantThrows" and "JavadocMethod" checks. The error is "Unable to find class information for X". Searching online we've found that the solution is to add the compiled classes to the classpath before running Checkstyle.

Our problem is that our Checkstyle audit currently runs on a server that only has access to the source and we just want to confirm that Checkstyle will in fact need access to compiled classes. Can't seem to find "definitive proof" on the official site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkstyle is perfectly happy with the source files only. Compiled versions of your classes are not required.

However, it is still better to have compiled classes available, because a few individual checks do make use of compiled .class files. These checks mention the fact that they need binaries in their documentation. One is the *[JavadocMethod](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocMethod)* check you mention. This one will still function without binaries, but you may see some irritation in the logs.

The other check I can think of needing compiled classes is *[RedundantThrows](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#RedundantThrows)*. This one will probably not do much good with only sources. You'd have to give it a try.

In both cases, you can suppress the load errors by setting the `suppressLoadErrors` property to `true`. Without binaries, the check will not be able to gather inheritance information. So some features of the check will be limited, but it will otherwise work fine or at least not bother you.

Comment: Recently, the Checkstyle team recommends to provide compiled classes, as they use them in an increasing number of checks. Checkstyle still works without, though.